# finding cross browser compatibility issue

Tags: css, cross-browser, rendering

I have designed a site that shows nice via FF or Chrome while fails to render with IE. I am looking for some kind of software inorder to find the parts that causes the render issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS validation you can use the following links

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload+with_options

http://tester.jonasjohn.de/

But mainly some of these CSS issues will be a bug in the browser and you cannot find them using CSS validators. For that you have to manually detect and replace them with alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will be a trial and error effort. Microsoft does have a developer toolbar but if you are doing anything really complex its not going to be the best help.

[IEDeveloper Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)